# sorted result of inorder traversal on binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a question about Binary Trees:

There is a binary tree T1 with n members. 
    When we run inorder traversal on T1 then we get a series from 1 to n (1,2,3,...n).
    Now is T1 a BST (Binary Search Tree)?

I know that if T1 is BST an inorder traversal will result a sorted series but is the oposite direction will work also?

Comment: What do you mean by opposite direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes..

Binary Search property is every node on left tree is lesser and every node on right is greater.

Considering that at any sub tree in your case since we are traversing in-order and saw every element before them is lesser and we are ascending when travelling to the right we have the BST...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds too homeworkish so no direct answer. But:

Assume the root has value `k`.

Now try this: what does is means for a node to be appearing to the left of `k` in the in order traversal? On the right?

Also, the numbers appearing before `k` are all smaller than `k`. What does that help this question here?

Comment: helps for me, because in inorder traversal we check the sub left tree then the root and then the right sub tree. then i realize how easy this question. thank you!